# Parallel.ForEach throws exception when processing extremely large sets of data

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, parallel-processing, linq-to-objects, large-data-volumes

My question centers on some Parallel.ForEach code that used to work without fail, and now that our database has grown to 5 times as large, it breaks almost regularly.

```
Parallel.ForEach<Stock_ListAllResult>( lbStockList.SelectedItems.Cast<Stock_ListAllResult>(), SelectedStock =>
{
    ComputeTipDown( SelectedStock.Symbol );
} );
```

The ComputeTipDown() method gets all daily stock tic data for the symbol, and iterates through each day, gets yesterday's data and does a few calculations and then inserts them into the database for each day.

We use this rarely to recalculate static data values when a formula changes.

The exception is this:

[image]

The database we are hitting has 16 gigs of ram and is a dual quad-core and nobody was using the system while I was recalculating.  The machine running the application to regenerate the code is a laptop with 12 gigs of ram with a hyper-threaded octal-core.  So there was no obvious resource contention.

This is my foray into using .NET 4 and parallel processing, so I am wondering if there is something I am missing.  Any thoughts would be welcomed.

Comment: any solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you received an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx), which is what Parallel.ForEach will raise if any of the loop body methods raise an exception.

If you debug this, you should be able to look at the [InnerExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions.aspx) to see the actual exceptions thrown.  It looks like `ComputeTipDown` raised an exception in one or more of your iterations, causing this to occur.

Comment: Reed, thank you very much for the suggestion, I'll put a breakpoint in the catch for ComputeTipDown and will see what happens.

Comment: @MikeMalter: You can also wrap the Parallel.ForEach in a try/catch, and catch AggregateException.  This will give you the details at that point...

Comment: I read that by clicking on the AggregateException link you provided in your answer.  I just got another exception, and this time it was the "real" one.  Max pool size was reached.  Interesting.  I upgraded the server this weekend to 2008 r2 and SQL Server to 2008 R2, and it was after that this started happing with regular frequency.

Comment: @MikeMalter: Are you running this as an x64 process?  In x86, the default max thread size is quite a bit smaller...

Comment: @MikeMalter: Is "ComputeTipDown" using a database internally?  If so, you're probably hitting the max db connection pool.  If that's the problem, you may want to set ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParalellism and use a different overload of ForEach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx